# How to rewrite ArrayList in opposite direction

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, arraylist, while-loop

I have a ArrayList and I need to rewrite it in the opposite direction. How to do it?

```
List<Posts> viewList = new ArrayList<Posts>(); 
viewList = viewLogic.getPostsList(username);
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)?

Comment: Just google the problem. I think there are more than 1000 examples for that use case out there.

Comment: @Ziyao Wei - that should be an answer.

Comment: @DonRoby Too trivial:) I don't feel too comfortable doing that, although I might missed ~+20:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use:

```
Collections.reverse(viewList);
```

As documented by Oracle [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29)

Answer (score 0):

Just simple for loop will do:

```
for (int i=viewList.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
    System.out.println(viewList.get(i));
```

Please note that this will not alter the original order of the `viewList`.

Answer (score 0):

This will work.I tested it

```
 ArrayList<String>  list=new ArrayList<String>();
       String tmp=null;
       int w=list.size()/2;
       for(int i=0;i<w;i++){
           tmp=list.get(i);
           list.set(i, list.get(list.size()-1-i));
           list.set(list.size()-1-i, tmp);
       }
```